# Recover data after failure , cache schema version mismatch

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes, glusterfs

The cassandra Filesystem is on a glusterFS, after scaling the number of pods to zero, and back up to 3, the data is not loading up into cassandra.

Is there a way to recover it?

```
INFO  17:00:52 reading saved cache /cassandra_data/saved_caches/KeyCache-d.db
INFO  17:00:52 Harmless error reading saved cache /cassandra_data/saved_caches/KeyCache-d.db
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cache schema version c2a2bb4f-7d31-3fb8-a216-00b41a643650 does not match current schema version 59adb24e-f3cd-3e02-97f0-5b395827453f
at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache.loadSaved(AutoSavingCache.java:198) ~[apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache$3.call(AutoSavingCache.java:157) [apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
at org.apache.cassandra.cache.AutoSavingCache$3.call(AutoSavingCache.java:153) [apache-cassandra-3.3.jar:3.3]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log you're showing is an **harmless error**. Basically it is just saying that the cache file is no longer in sync.

> INFO  17:00:52 **Harmless error** reading saved cache /cassandra_data/saved_caches/KeyCache-d.db